# ContentTools - Unable to reactivate with custom Edit button

Tags: javascript, html

Im using ContentTools and everything works as expected when using the standard Ignition. However when I instead of using the Blue button add my own to Start editing/Save and Discard changes the Editor is unable to reactivate. This means that the user can Edit, then Save once. All subsequent attempts at reactivation fail silently.

Init code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
    editor.init('.editable', 'id');
    ContentTools.IMAGE_UPLOADER = imageUploader;

    $('#btnStartEdit').click(function() {
        editor.start();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeIn();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#btnSaveChanges').click(function() {
        editor.save();
        $('#btnStartEdit').fadeIn();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeOut();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeOut();

    });
    $('#btnDiscardChanges').click(function() {
        editor.revert();
        $('#btnStartEdit').fadeIn();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeOut();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeOut();
    });
    ContentTools.EditorApp.get()._ignition.unmount();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `save()` and `revert()` methods directly I recommend you use `stop(true)` for save and `stop(false)` for cancel/revert.

The `save` and `revert` methods don't stop the editor (for example `save(true)` can be used to auto-save content while the user continues to edit). Using `stop` should allow you to restart the editor, e.g:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
    editor.init('.editable', 'id');
    ContentTools.IMAGE_UPLOADER = imageUploader;

    $('#btnStartEdit').click(function() {
        editor.start();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeIn();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#btnSaveChanges').click(function() {
        editor.stop(true);
        $('#btnStartEdit').fadeIn();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeOut();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeOut();

    });
    $('#btnDiscardChanges').click(function() {
        editor.stop(false);
        $('#btnStartEdit').fadeIn();
        $('#btnSaveChanges').fadeOut();
        $('#btnDiscardChanges').fadeOut();
    });
    ContentTools.EditorApp.get()._ignition.unmount();
});
```

Comment: That did the trick and makes perfect sense, thank you very much!